# What is the role of applyDesign in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7. I am working on extension for quick view of product. I am unable to understand the following code.

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/design')->applyDesign($product, Mage_Catalog_Model_Design::APPLY_FOR_PRODUCT);
```

can anybody tell me what is the purpose of this function `applyDesign` because i have tried comment this line but no change happened so i am wondering why this code used for ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ref. [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Design::applyDesign()` (link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Design.php#L58).

It's a deprecated method for applying the package+theme design settings which can be set at the product level. If you are not seeing a change, it is because there is no entity-level data set for that entity (which is normal).